# Regex Code - variable numeric before match string

Tags: regex

The string that my current regex is getting from this source code

```
":3},"caption":"Coffee","likes"
```

with this regex that I use in regex101's site:

```
":.},"(.*?)"likes"
```

The problem now is, that sometimes the numbers change in their length. to make things more clear.

It could be one digit like the example above:

```
":3},"caption":"Coffee","likes"
```

Or it can be two digit long

```
":64},"caption":"Coffee","likes"
```

Or three digit long

```
":423},"caption":"Coffee","likes"
```

Etc.

How can I edit my regex above and make it so that it does the matching for one digit long, two digit long etc. numbers in the code?

I have tried this:

```
":.|..|...},"(.*?)"likes"
```

It wasn't the most elegant way to solve things, also it simply doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can match any amount of digits with `\d+`, if you only want 1 up to 3 digits you can use `\d{1,3}`. This leads to either

```
":\d+},"(.*?)"likes"
```

or

```
":\d{1,3}},"(.*?)"likes"
```

Comment: I added `[0-9]{1,5}` to say that the number can be between 1 and 5 [1,10,100,1000,10000] digits and each number cna be something between 0 and 9 [1,2,3,4,5...]. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is - however you might want to use the `+` modifier (one or more) in case you will have more than 5 digits in the future.

Comment: `[0-9]{1,5}+` like this?

Comment: No, `[0-9]+` (which is the same as `\d+`)

Comment: Or `\d{1,5}` or `[0-9]{1,5}` to say 1 to 5 digits.